# Understanding functional composition example in Untyped $\lambda$-Calculus

Tags: calculus, functions, logic

The following equalities are shown as an application of $\alpha, \beta, \eta$-conversion found within Untyped $\lambda$-Calculus. I am unable to reconcile the first equality. Is the example missing a $41$ in the text or I am missing something?
$$
\begin{split}
+21\, 31 &= ((+21) 31) + (+21\, 31) 41\\
&=(+((+21) 31) 41 )\\
&=((fg)x)=(fg)x=fgx
\end{split}
$$

Comment: `\ `  causes a space

Comment: What is the question? It is not clear at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are *two separate examples* to express how to eliminate the parenthesis when everything applies from the left. 
$$+\ 21\ 31\ =\ ((+21)\,31)\\
+(+\ 21\ 31)\ 41\ =\ (+((+21)\,31)\,41)$$
Here, for example, $(+21)$ means the (lambda) function that 'adds $21$' to its (only) argument, $(+21)\,31$ reduces to $52$ and $(+\,52)\,41$ reduces to $93$.